# Attempting to run transaction which calls a contract function, but recipient address is not a contract address

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have created a solidity contract where I can store application

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Applications {

  address applicant;

  mapping(uint => string) Application;

  function Applications() internal {
    applicant = msg.sender;
  } 

  modifier ifApplicant() {
    if (applicant != msg.sender) {
      revert();
    } else {
      _;
    }
  }

  function setApplication(uint id, string data) public {
    Application[id] = data;
  }

  function getApplication(uint id) ifApplicant public view returns (string) {
     return Application[id];
  }
}
```

When I try to access the setApplication method via web3 I get the above error `Attempting to run transaction which calls a contract function, but recipient address is not a contract address`

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const contract = require('truffle-contract');

const web3 = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545')
);
const ApplicationContract = require('./../blockchain/build/contracts/Applications.json');
const application = contract(ApplicationContract);
//web3 has deprecated sendAsync func whereas truffle-contract relies on it - this is patch hack
web3.currentProvider.sendAsync = web3.currentProvider.send;
application.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

web3.eth.getAccounts().then(accounts => {
        application.new(
            {
                from: accounts[0],
                data:
                    '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',
                gas: '4700000',
            }   
        ).then((contract) => {if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
                    const ApplicationContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
                        application.abi,
                        contract.address
                    );
                    ApplicationContract.methods
                        .setApplication(1, 'form')
                        .call({ from: accounts[0] })
                        .then(data => console.log(data))
                        .catch(err => console.log(err));
                    console.log(
                        'Contract mined! address: ' +
                            contract.address +
                            ' transactionHash: ' +
                            contract.transactionHash
                    );
                }
            });
```

I am running `ganache-cli` for local development.

PS: I am very new to Solidity

Comment: `.call().send(...)` looks suspicious. Do one or the other. (You probably want `send` here, so `methods.setApplication(1, 'from').send(...)`.)

Comment: But also, probably `ApplicationContract.methods.setApplication...`, right? Or what is `methods`?

Comment: @smarx Corrected. Yes, you are right.  I get the same error when I do setApplication.call({from: ''}) and I invoke send I get error 
VM4711:1 Error: Returned error: sender account not recognized

Comment: It looks like you're trying to send the transaction from the contract's address. You can't do that. Use `web3.eth.accounts` to see what accounts `ganache` knows about. You can send transactions from those.

Comment: @smarx i have got the contract address from remix and fetched the accounts from getAccounts api, even then I get the same error. I see the latest web3 has changed quite lot of api's.

Comment: Can you update your question with your current code and the current error?

Comment: @smarx I have updated the code. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: That code looks okay (though a `call` won't actually change any state, so you'll want to change that eventually). I can only assume the address is wrong. Can you be specific about exactly how you obtained that address? (What environment did you deploy to, where exactly was the address, etc.?)

Comment: I got the contract address from `https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.4.21+commit.dfe3193c.js` while creating the contract. I copied the address over. I am not sure if that the right way?

Comment: Please answer my questions. They were designed to help you to be more specific about how you obtained the address.

Comment: I have edited the code. I have copied the snippet to deploy contract from remix but now it throws the error stating `Error: Applications contract constructor expected 0 arguments, received 2`

Comment: Looks like I was confusing the truffle-contract new api with web3 new. I think I have sorted the issue. thanks @smarx

Answer (score 4):

Run this from your command line

`truffle networks --clean`

this will clean your local network of previously built network...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using call for a write operation, where it should be used to just read values from Blockchain.

> ApplicationContract.methods
>                           .setApplication(1, 'form')
>                           .call

Replace the call with a sendTransaction and it should work.

Please read web3.eth.call vs web3.eth.sendTransaction

For your reference
[What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call)

Answer (score 1):

I removed build/contracts folders and re-run :

1. `truffle build`
2. `truffle migrate`

After that, the error message disappears.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/56231) explains what is causing this error. Running `truffle migrate --reset` should fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Try it.

```
var adoptionInstance;

web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {

    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    var account = accounts[0];
    App.contracts.ApplicationContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    contractInstance = instance;
    //Execute adopt as a transaction by sending account
    console.log("Pedding Function");
    return contractInstance.setApplication(1,'form', {from: account, value: web3.toWei(prices, "ether")});
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log("Success Adopt");
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("Error Adopt " + err.message);
});
});
```